# Custom redirect URL after successfull SAML login

Tags: php, symfony, saml, saml-2.0

I'm using [Lightsaml](https://www.lightsaml.com/SP-Bundle/Getting-started/) and [simplesamlphp](https://simplesamlphp.org/) as SSO-Solution. Basic Setup is fine, but I need to implement a custom redirect URL.
Let's say User is on example.com/shop, clicked on example.com/login, get's redirected to my IDP and I want to redirect him back to example.com/shop after successfull login, not example.com/login.

Thanks for helping

Chris

Comment: What is the basic setup? What doesn't work? What is the actual code?

Comment: Basic Setup is as described in the links I provided. So authenticating through the IDP and redirecting the user to my Symfony App is all working. As described in the Question, I am looking for a way, to dynamically set the Redirect URL. There is also no code to provide, cause I don't know the part of the Lightsaml Library where this part is handled.